# What are some methods that one use to move files with java?

Tags: java, deployment, zip, installation, unpack

I was working on a installer for a program that i'm making, it uses a zip file, and for some reason I can't find a way to unpack and install the files from a zip folder. If somebody could help me I would be VERY happy.

Comment: Might take a look at this API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Comment: *"I was working on a installer for a program"*  Use [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) as the installer!

Comment: Take a look through the java.util.zip API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) and see if anything in there can help you.

Comment: Also you should be aware this library exists: http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html  In general, if there's a commons lib for it, that means it's an easier API to use than what the standard library provides.

Comment: The first hurdle an installer needs to overcome is to ensure a suitable JRE is installed.  To create a 'bare bones' installer on top of that is not a trivial task.  To create an installer that can do anything *more* than a bare bones install (auto-update, use natives, desktop integration) is a task of huge proportions.  Since there are already a *lot* of existing installers (e.g. JWS, Launch4J, JSmooth, ..) that can do that, it seems a waste of effort to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for unzipping your files:

```
String zipName = "my.zip";
String installDir = "/home/user/installDir";
try
{
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipName);
    files = zipFile.entries();
    while (files.hasMoreElements())
    {
         ZipEntry zipEntry = files.nextElement();
         if(zipEntry.isDirectory())
         {
                (new File(installDir + zipEntry.getName())).mkdir();
                 continue;
         }
         InputStream in = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
         File newFile = new File("/home/user/tmp/testdit" + File.separator + zipEntry.getName());

         new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int len;

         while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
         {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
         }

         in.close();
         fos.close();
       }
   } catch (IOException ex)
   {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

While `java.util.zip` and Apache commons-io provide nice mechanisms to read data out of a zip file in Java, if you actually want to unpack a zip file onto disk preserving the directory structure then the easiest Java API for that is probably Apache Ant.

```
Project p = new Project();
p.init();
Expand ex = new Expand();
ex.setProject(p);
ex.setSrc(new File("myArchive.zip"));
ex.setDest(new File("targetDir"));
ex.perform();
```

But as other commenters have noted, you should probably consider using an existing installer building tool such as [IZPack](http://izpack.org) rather than reinvent the wheel.